# Output only certain fields

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Been looking for a way to output a certain field in a line, and only the next field after it.

So say I have file with the contents "*blue, green, purple, orange, black, white,* ", how would I search for the word "*purple,* ", and print to screen only "*purple, orange,*".

I need to omit the "*black, white,*" from the output.

```
cat filename | sed -n -e 's/^.*\(purple\)/\1/p'
purple, orange, black, white,
```

Comment: Don't `cat file | sed 'stuff'`; just `sed 'stuff' file`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ grep -o 'purple, [^,]*' input
purple, orange
```

The `-o` switch prints **o**nly the string matching the pattern.

The pattern is the string `purple,`, followed by zero or more characters which are anything other than a comma.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking forward. Thanks DopeGhoti :)

Comment: Glad to hear it!  When you have a moment, please mark the answer as 'Accepted' so that others know the question is no longer seeking an answer.  Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: Done. Thanks again. First time questioner so still learning the ropes on this forum.